# Visual Studio 2013 and MSBuild Incremental Build Incompatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm working on a project that has a fairly standard Visual Studio 2013 build chain. One of the projects within the solution is used solely for compiling .hlsl files into .cso files, which are then loaded at runtime. When building from within the Visual Studio IDE, incremental builds behave as expected; if I edit color_ps.hlsl only that shader is compiled into its corresponding .cso file.

In the interest of expediting developer workflow, we have a system which automatically recompiles and then reloads shaders at runtime. Essentially, if the application is running and a user edits color_ps.hlsl, I launch MSBuild from the application to rebuild the project containing our shaders, and then reload its corresponding .cso file. Incremental builds here work as expected.

This all works fantastically, the only problem being that it seems that there seem to be some incompatibilities across the IDE and MSBuild. The first time compiling with MSBuild at runtime, **all .hlsl files within the project are rebuilt.** Further re-builds use incremental building as expected.

Furthermore, after exiting the application, attempting to build the shader project **from within the Visual Studio IDE also triggers a full rebuild.** Following re-builds use incremental building as expected.

My suspicion as to why this occurs is that the IDE and MSBuild do not recognize that their outputs are already up-to-date. To clarify, the output assemblies produced by compiling from the IDE and MSBuild **are identical**, and as such should be recognized as being up-to-date regardless of from where the build is being invoked.

Would anyone know a way to prevent these needless full-rebuilds when switching between building from the IDE versus invoking MSBuild at runtime? Thanks!

Comment: Although in theory msbuild running on the command line and in the ide ought to be the same, some targets execute differently in each scenario, based on the $(running in visualstudio) property. I would run each build with high verbosity and compare the outputs, paying attention to whether the inputs and outputs are considered up to date. For msbuild.exe use /v:d and for the ide use the options dialog to output with higher verbosity

Comment: You'll have to dig through the detailed log you get from jacking up the verbosity.  The task is named FxCompile, the fxc*.tlog files in the project's tlog directory matter to decide what gets built.